# asp.net core Automapper with unknown model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

my system has a register of clients, suppliers, users, resellers, and they all have the same fields to enter the address, so I decided to create a ViewComponent to show in the editing screen of all the views, I pass as parameter to the creation of the component the current model of the view which can be clients.cs, vendors.cs, users.cs or resellers.cs, so that when the component is created, already have filled in the address data, the problem that I am not able to map the Model passed to the Model of Address.cs

My ViewComponent:

```
    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(object model)
    {
        var enderecoViewModel = Mapper.Map<model , EnderecoViewModel>(model); //<<=ERROR
        return View("Endereco", enderecoViewModel);
    }
```

My view that loads the viewcomponent:

```
@model PetAlerta.Domain.Entities.suppliers
...
...
@await Component.InvokeAsync("Endereco", new { model = Model });
```

another:

```
@model PetAlerta.Domain.Entities.resellers
...
...
@await Component.InvokeAsync("Endereco", new { model = Model });
```

I have the Model EnderecoViewModel.cs which has all the address fields of the Model sent in the component parameter.

Is it possible to do that? The idea is not to have to create the repeated html for all the screens that have the same fields.

Comment: Why not make all your classes implement an IAddress interface and the use that as the generic parameter in your map() call instead of an object?

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dynamic-and-ExpandoObject-Mapping.html

Comment: Go with @CalC's recommendation. Instead of accepting `object` as your view component param, accept `IAddress` instead. Then make each class implement that interface and setup a mapping from `IAddress` to your `EnderecoViewModel` class. Done.

Comment: I'll do it, thank you!